# Build debian preseed after the options selected on a normal installation

Tags: debian, unattended

Is there any way to build the pre-seed file based on the options I've chosen manually, instead of writing one from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a command like `debconf-get-selections --installer` on a installed system to dump most of the configuration used to build that system.  This file probably will need to be adjusted a bit, but it will give you a pretty good starting point.

- https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apbs03.html.en